# How to decrease the volume of an audio element, gradually by pressing a button

Tags: javascript, html, audio, volume

I am trying to figure out a way to incrementally lower the volume of audio in HTML using JavaScript. I would like to simply press a HTML button, and for that button to lower the volume of audio gradually, and for it to cut out upon reaching zero.

I have tried to find the answer to this problem online, but there are no resources out there on how to achieve this. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

This is my attempt at solving this problem in JavaScript;

```
var decreaseVolume
var birds = document.getElementById("$audio");

function rampdown(){
  var maxVolume = 100;
  decreaseVolume = setInterval(function(){
    if (maxVolume == 0) {
      clearInterval(decreaseVolume);
      birds.volume = "0";
    } else {
      birds.volume = rampdown;
    }
    rampdown -= 1;
  }, 30);

}
```

I have created a button in HTML with onclick="rampdown()", but it doesn't do anything to the volume. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: is there an error in the console? Did you verify it is called?

Comment: Yes, the error states: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set properties of null (setting 'volume'). This is in reference to the line  birds.volume = rampdown;

Comment: So it did not find the element! `console.log( birds );` is going to be null

Comment: Your element really has a $ in the id?

Comment: It does. I have changed it to other id names, but still no luck.

Comment: So you are probably referencing the element before it exists. If you move `var birds = document.getElementById("$audio");` inside of the function does it start to work?

Comment: I moved it, but if I do that I still get errors. I've also adjusted the HTML DOM position of the script, but that hasn't helped either.

Comment: It is impossible for me to guess why it can not find the element. Is the audio element added dynamically? what does the HTML look like? We need more details.

Comment: Your code with some adjustments .... https://jsfiddle.net/epascarello/aLxr13zd/

Comment: Thank you epascarello! This is exactly what I was after! You're a legend!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Volume is 0 to 1, not 0 to 100

```js
var decreaseVolume
var birds = document.getElementById("$audio");
console.log(birds.volume)

function rampdown(){
  var maxVolume = 100;
  decreaseVolume = setInterval(function(){
    if (maxVolume == 0) {
      clearInterval(decreaseVolume);
      birds.volume = "0";
    } else {
      birds.volume = maxVolume/100;
    }
    maxVolume -= 1;
  }, 30);
}
```

```html
<audio id="$audio" controls src="https://file-examples.com/storage/fef1706276640fa2f99a5a4/2017/11/file_example_MP3_700KB.mp3"></audio>
<button id="reduce" type="button" onclick="rampdown()">reduce</button>
```